# Two mouses one Mac

Tags: macos, mouse

Remember this old [Easter egg from Google link](https://www.google.com/chrome/multitask.html).

I want to know: is it possible to have the cursors from two mouses on one Mac? I am able to dualscreen.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The [Google Multitask Mode](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/multitask.html) is one of Google's fantastic April Fools jokes. Although technically possible to connect multiple pointing devices (USB mouses, Bluetooth mouses, trackpads, rollerballs, etc.) so far as I can tell, OS X presents only one cursor for all connected devices. This posting at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/649325/two-mice-two-pointers-one-mac) discusses this question, and one answer points to [this software](http://multicursor-wm.sourceforge.net/) as a possible solution. YMMV.

Note: my boss just came into my office as I was testing this by using two hands on USB-connected mouses, and my nose on the Magic Trackpad. All three moved a single cursor, as expected. I just got a raise for ingenuity and creativity.